# fakeAsync instead of async testing angular two-way binding

Tags: angular, asynchronous, testing, jasmine

I got a test for this textarea in my component:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="result"></textarea>
```

And a working test using async:

```
it('Using async', async(() => {
    const result = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('textarea'));
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(result.nativeElement.value).toBe('Value');
    });
}));
```

This works fine. But I'm trying to do the same with fakeAsync it doesn't work:

```
it('Using fakeAsync', fakeAsync(() => {
    const result = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('textarea'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    expect(component.result).toBe('Value'); //--> This works fine
    expect(result.nativeElement.value).toBe('Value'); //-->this doesn't
}));
```

Can you help me?